# Make transaction fail with conflict if a row previously read is changed by a concurrent transaction

Tags: sql-server, isolation-level, snapshot-isolation

If a row is modified by a transaction that uses the SNAPSHOT isolation level, any concurrent update (by another transaction) to the same row causes the SNAPSHOT transaction to fail with a conflict.

Is there a way to have the same behavior happen with rows that have only been read (not necessarily modified)?

As an example, I am looking to have TX1 fail with conflict if the following sequence happens:

1. TX1 starts with SNAPSHOT isolation level
2. TX1 reads row 1
3. TX2 modifies row 1 and commits
4. TX1 commits, and fail with a conflict as row 1 has been modified after it has been read

Comment: That will anyways happens as a result of snapshot isolation level. What exactly you are asking here?

Comment: That is not what I am seeing. The transaction only fails is TX1 modifies row 1. If it only reads it, no conflict is raised.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see that; you are just reading not doing any modification. Why you want that behavior BTW?

Comment: I am making an update that depends on the value I read, but these are two separate rows. If the value read has changed, the update is no longer valid, should fail and be reattempted.

Comment: You could start a txn and use isolation level of "repeatable read"